# sslcontextbuilder and SSLContexts deprecated

Tags: java, apache, ssl

I am using JDK1.8 with JDK Compilance JavaSE-1.7, Eclipse Luna, and Apache httpclient 4.4.1.

I am getting warning in Eclipse that `sslcontextbuilder` and `SSLContexts` are deprecated. What are alternatives for these classes?

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK?

Comment: Can you please provide us some more information? Which eclipse, which JDK and which library are you using?

Comment: I am using JDK1.8  with JDK Compilance JavaSE-1.7, Eclipse Luna                      And Apache httpclient 4.4.1 version.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have actually just been looking at this and it appears that the HttpCLient SSLContexts class is in the process of being moved from `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts` to `org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts`. I changed my imports to these new packages and it appears to be good now.  Not sure what your reference is for `sslcontextbuilder` but I am pretty sure it has an alternate implementation as well.  Let me know more details and I can check.

Answer (score 1):

you can change it as below code

```java
// Fixing deprecated code to use current HttpClient implementations      Sekito.Lv 01/30/2019 11:29     Start
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;

//import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts;
//import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
// Fixing deprecated code to use current HttpClient implementations      Sekito.Lv 01/30/2019 11:29     End
```