# Cannot resolve method 'loadTrustMaterial'

Tags: java, android

I am using Android studio (in Linux) to make a project and in which I had to write code by which I can accept all the certificates. But the problem I am facing while using `TrustSelfSignedStrategy` is that when I pass this through `builder.loadTrustMaterial`, it shows something like *Cannot resolve method 'loadTrustMaterial'(null,org.apache.http.conn.TrustSelfSignedStrategy)*. 
A screenshot has been attached. However, the same code is working in Eclipse with the same library.

[image: loadTrustMaterial Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`loadTrustMaterial`**](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLContextBuilder.html#loadTrustMaterial(java.security.KeyStore,%20org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustStrategy))

```
 public SSLContextBuilder loadTrustMaterial(KeyStore truststore,
                                  TrustStrategy trustStrategy)
                                    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                                           KeyStoreException
```

You should use [**`TrustStrategy`**](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/TrustStrategy.html) instead of **`TrustSelfSignedStrategy`**.

```
TrustStrategy trust_stgOBJ = new TrustStrategy()
```

**FYI**

> Moved from org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts to
>   org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.

Read [**`sslcontextbuilder and SSLContexts deprecated`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30760110/3395198).